# What is the proper ansi c example for windows?

Tags: c, windows, turbo-c

Some books claim that they used ansi c and use turbo c compiler to run these example. i tried to run these on linux but I found that these example are only for windows.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
/* #include<dos.h> */
int main()
{
    int a;
    clrscr();
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("%d",a);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Can I call the above example ansi c? why or why not?

Comment: that because clrscr() and getch() are nonstandard in c language. some compilers implement it, but it has no relation with the system used.

Comment: They are just library functions.  Not that you can easily use them on Windows either, it does require a product from a museum.  Linux programmers usually swear at curses.h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @milevyo said, those functions are implemented by Borland's compilers. On Windows you can replace `clrscr()` with `system("cls")` and `getch();` with `_getch();` or, even better, `getchar()`.

Comment: what is about the claim that this book is using ansi c? is it wrong or right?

Comment: @MRMillon Actually is valid ANSI C, just not cross platform (as far as I know Turbo C is for Windows) nor compiler (not part of the standard).

Answer (score 0):

`conio.h` file directory is only supported by `Borland C`.You can use `getchar()` instead of `getch()`.

If you have to use `getch()` anyhow then You can use `curses.h` file instead of `conio.h`. It gives mostly all the functionality of `conio.h` with `getch()`.

If you don't get `curses.h` directory installed then you can download from [here](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/lib/libcurses/curses.h?rev=1.86&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

int main()
{
    initscr();              /* start the curses mode */
    int a;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("%d",a);

    getch();
    endwin();

 return 0;
}
```